# Nox emulator startup stuck at 99%

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I am using windows 7, im using nox as device to debug in android studio
Then, Nox starts normally but the startup progress always stuck at 99%.

here is the log file:

> 2017-10-25 22:31:28 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[ERROR] vm:nox status: 5
>
> 2017-10-25 22:31:29 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[INFO] port_valid_check return
>   true
>
> 2017-10-25 22:32:32 [NoxPlayerWindow]-[ERROR] boot timeout will
>   exit_application
>
> 2017-10-25 22:32:33 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0nox_adb.exe
>
> 2017-10-25 22:32:33 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 1NoxVMSVC.exe
>
> 2017-10-25 22:32:33 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 1BigNoxProxy.exe
>
> 2017-10-25 22:32:33 [Utils]-[INFO] Kill 0NoxVMHandle.exe

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable HyperV under Windows Features.